# Eclipse changes class path on its own

Tags: java, android, eclipse, classpath

I am working on an Android project in Eclipse. For some reason, it wants to automatically export Android Private Libraries and Android Dependencies whenever I first open the workspace. This causes things to crash and burn (specifically - Conversion to Dalvik Format failed with error 1). My laptop does this and my desktop does not (I am using SVN). Any ideas on setting is doing this? The fix is easy, just override the local version with the correct version from SVN).

Any ideas on why it's doing this and how to stop it? It's just an annoyance really but I would still like to fix it.

Comment: Look at the project classpath and Andorid Environment setup in Eclipse? It will not do it on its own, unless specified in configuration. And also please verify the contents of .classpath file between two systems in the project folder. You will be able to find what's going on.

Comment: Will check. I promise it's doing it on its own as soon as I open Eclipse, but only on the laptop. They both have the exact same folder structure and both have the library I need to reference (Box Android Library) in the workspace. Just weird.

Comment: You will find more information if you can look at .classpath file in the project folder in both scenarios to see if project in laptop contains more classpath entries?

Comment: Same number of entries. It just adds exported=true to the lines having to do with the libraries/dependencies. Nothing else changes except for those.

Comment: remove exported= true in classpath and clean and build it.

Comment: That's what I've been doing. It stays fine until I close the workspace and go back in. Then it changes it.

Comment: It seems maybe your SVN is corrupted if this continue to happens after you pull a correct version. Do other people have access to it?

Comment: Compare the .classpath with the one in SVN. It willn't pull unless you  explicitly update or if you have any setting to update workspace automatically.

Comment: I can't find any setting to mess with that. I'll just fix it manually each time.

Comment: It's annoying... tried submitting bug to 'droid: [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60128)